# XML file not showing properly when loaded with Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

I created a small XML file like following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Helical>
    <modeA>
        <thickness value = "1mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
        <thickness value = "2mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
    </modeA>
    <modeB>
        <thickness value = "0.6mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
        <thickness value = "1.2mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
    </modeB>
 </Helical>

<AxialRebin2D>
    <modeA>
        <thickness value = "1.2mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
        <thickness value = "2.4mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
    </modeA>
    <modeB>
        <thickness value = "0.6mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
        <thickness value = "1.2mm">
            <kernel SMOOTH="1.0013" SMOOTH_PLUS="0.0583" STANDARD="1.0000"/>
        </thickness>
    </modeB>
</AxialRebin2D>
```

However, when I was double clicking it, loaded with IE, nothing showed up on the webpage. I figure there must be something wrong with my formatting? I have no clue how to edit a XML file though. Can anyone give a pointer where it was messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "XML" is not ***[well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)*** (and therefore not really XML at all) because it has **multiple root elements**: `Helical` and `AxialRebin2D`.  You'll have to remove one of the root elements or wrap them both in a common root element.